# vue unexpected reactivity from props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I just noticed an unexpected behaviour and now I don't know if it is normal or not.

I have a component named `follows` and a child component named `follow-list-modal`

I'm passing a `followList` (pagination )  from `follows` to  its child component `follow-list-modal`

In the `follow-list-modal` I store the paginated array in the variable `members`

```
Follows.vue
```

```
<template>
   <div>
         <follow-list-modal
           :follow-list="dataset">
          </follow-list-modal>
  
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
props: {
   dataset: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

```
FollowListModal.vue
```

```
<template>
   <div>
      <button @click="fetchMore"> More </button>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
props: {
   followList: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
data() {
    return {
      members: this.followList.data,
      dataset: this.followList,
    };
  },
methods: {
    fetchMore() {
            let nextPage = parseInt(this.dataset.current_page)  + 1;
            axios
              .get(this.dataset.path + '?page=' + nextPage)
              .then(({ data }) => this.refresh(data))
              .catch((error) => console.log(error));
           }
},
refresh(paginatedCollection) {
      this.dataset = paginatedCollection;
      this.members = this.members.concat(...paginatedCollection.data);
    },
}
```

When I click the button `More` in the `follow-list-modal` to get more data, I then want to append the new data to the `members` array.

The **unexpected behaviour**  ( for me at least ). is that if I use `push` in the `refresh` method

```
this.members.push(..paginatedCollection.data);
```

It appends data **not only** to `members` **but also** to `followList` which is data that comes from the parent component `follows`

But if I use `concat` instead of `push`, it appends data only to `members` variable and not to `followList`

```
this.members = this.members.concat(..paginatedCollection.data);
```

Is this behaviour normal ?

I don't get why the `followList` changes when the `members` variable changes, I thought that reactivity is one way.

In other words, the `members` changes when the `followList` changes, but not the other way around

**P.S** I don't emit any events from `follow-list-modal` to `follows` or change the data of the `follows` component in any way from the `follow-list-modal`

Comment: see the final note of this section in the Vue guide: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate your data with a direct link to the (initially undefined) property of your prop. This property is a complex entity like an Object (Arrays are Objects), and is thus called via reference. Since `members` references the same thing in memory as `followList.data`, when you're calling `members`, it will follow the reference to the same entity as `followList.data`. This doesn't have to do with Vue2 reactivity, [but here's a link nontheless.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

- `push` mutates the array it is called on; it will follow the reference through `members` and change `followList.data`, updating its value when called through followList as well. Because the `data` key is not present on instantiation of the component, Vue can't watch it (just like you need to use Vue.set when adding a new key to a data object).
- `concat` returns a new array of merged elements, and then replaces
  the reference in `members` with the new array. Therefore from this point on you'll
  no longer mutate `followList.data`, even with a push, as the reference has changed to a new entity.

---

When trying to set your initial `members` and `dataset`, I suggest using an initialization method that creates a clone of your followList and writes that to dataset, and running this on the `created()` or `mounted()` hook of your component lifecycle. Then create a computed property for `members`, no need to store followList.data thrice and potentially have dataset and members diverge.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, the properties of an Object that are also Objects themselves, are passed by reference, and not by value. Or you might say that they are `shallow copied`.

Thus, in your example, `this.members` and `this.followList.data` are pointing to the same variable in memory.
So, if you mutate `this.members`, it will mutate `this.followList.data` as well.

You could avoid this by doing a deep copy of the objects. The easiest method, and arguably the fastest, would be to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`, but [look at this answer for more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/4690525).

```
data() {
    return {
      members: [],
      dataset: [],
    };
},
created() {
    this.members = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.followList.data));
    this.dataset = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.followList));
}
```